# Wordpress As Backend Only

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dynamic, backend

So I have fully integrated my wordpress posts into my site, however now I am facing a dilemma... I want my URL's to be SEO friendly, for example:

My URL structure for a blog post is:

> blog-post.php?postid=1&type=singlePost

I would like the URL to read as the following:

> /blog/Title-Of-Article/

Of course "Title-Of-Article" would be dynamic. So how can I accomplish this. I am a fairly new coder and .htaccess is still pretty foreign to me.

---

I really need help with this, I have scoured the internet looking for solutions and have yet to see anything of use but I could just be not looking for the right thing. Thank you to anyone who has a solution to my problem.

Sorry if I wasn't clear enough, this is my first time posting here on stackoverflow. I only use wordpress as a backend admin for a blog section on my site that I have coded. I have everything integrated and working but I need to figure out how to use SEO friendly URLS on my dynamic php address:

> www.mysite.com/blog-post.php?postid=1&type=singlePost

### (notice how this file is in the base folder, NOT IN /blog/)

I want it to look like this:

> www.mysite.com/blog/Title-Of-Article/

Let me know what to do,
Thanks

Comment: You might get some help at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ You might also look at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html and in fact, anything by Ralf Engleschall.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you want to use the data in Wordpress to display posts without using Wordpress as a frontend? May I ask why you want to do that? Seems like a lot of work and you may able to simple just put your Wordpress install in a blog directory. Then your other code could run in the web root directory.

But if you really want to set up permalinks using Wordpress as a backend, you can do the following.

I'm assuming you're using urls like `/blog/blog-post.php?postid=1&type=singlePost`

I think I may be wrong about that though...

Anyway, you can just copy the default Wordpress .htaccess rules and put it in a directory named `blog`

Here is the .htaccess file, but with one change. You need to add `RewriteBase /blog/`

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Now every url in that looks like `/blog/my-article` or `/blog/category/cooking/how-to-cook` will be directed to `/blog/index.php`

This means you'd have to move your code from blog-post.php to `/blog/index.php`

Now in `index.php` you can retrieve the actually url using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. So if you visited `www.mysite.com/blog/category/cooking/how-to-cook`, you'd get `/blog/category/cooking/how-to-cook`.

Now you can parse the url to get the article name `how-to-cook` and use it as the id to grab your posts in `wp_posts`. This will be saved in `post_name` column.

Answer (score -1):

You dont need to touch htaccess. Just go to settings » permanent links and change default url structure for, lets say, post mame.

Comment: Read the question carefully. OP says he needs seo friendly permalinks for Backend not the front.

Comment: No sence to have seo friendly on backend. But you are right i dindt read carefully

Comment: Actually he didnt say permanent links only for back-end. He said backend on the title of the topic but then he asked for seo URLS. Not on backend. Read again.

Comment: Have a look at questions title. Also `?postid=1&type=singlePost` can only be seen in backend urls when updating existing posts.