# Seamless WordPress integration

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I have completely integrated WordPress into my website. Have installed wordpress in a folder called "/bl0g/". In my base folder I have a blog.php file setup (which displays latest 3 posts from wordpress) I have a blog-post.php file which displays an individual post if the variables after it are called correctly.

For example, if I navigate to:

> www.mywebsite.com/blog-post.php?postid=1&type=singlePost

The page loads the first blog post as it should. But what I am trying to accomplish is instead of calling the post by "postid" and "type" I would like to call the post buy its slug name.

I can accomplish echoing the slug name by using the following code:

```
<?php echo $post->post_name; ?>
```

But how can I call the article by slug in my code. And how can I then transform my url from:

This:

> www.mywebsite.com/blog-post.php?postid=1&type=singlePost

To this:

> www.mywebsite.com/blog-post.php?title=The-Slug-Of-This-Article

My reasoning for this is so that I can take this url and make it SEO friendly, by using .htaccess I will transform this URL to look like this:

> www.mywebsite.com/blog/The-Slug-Of-This-Article/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wordpress As Backend Only](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21612401/wordpress-as-backend-only). And the [other](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21666779/wordpress-custom-blog-post-page-url-rewrite) [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21636256/dynamic-url-rewrite-custom-wordpress-page). Please don't repost.

Comment: the surest way to get your questions closed it to say they're dupes. If you didn't get any attention on your original question, then edit that question and add more details. That'll bump it to the top of the queue.

Comment: listen I am reposting because my question has not been answered. Instead of correcting this you should help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. With respect, a key purpose of SO and other Stack Exchange sites is building a usable repository of crowd-sourced questions and answers. The rules about duplicate questions are in aid of that purpose. Lots of folks work hard on this. SO is not a forum site.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something here, but why don't you just set this in your permalinks settings in WordPress?  Going to Settings > Permalinks and selecting "Post name" under "Common Settings" would yield the end result you are looking for (i.e. www.mywebsite.com/blog/The-Slug-Of-This-Article/)

Comment: That doesnt help me at all I am not using wordpress for anything but a backend for writing content. When I make a post in Wordpress it appears outside of wordpress in some pages I have created that call functions from my wordpress folder.

Comment: Well you didn't say that in your question.  What you said was, "I have completely integrated WordPress into my website."